# iOS React Native app freezes with RCTSRWebSocketErrorDomain Thread 14: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: react-native, websocket

I recently upgraded my app to React Native version 0.54.2 and since then, iOS freezes after a few minutes of non-usage. Before the upgrade, this never happened. The error stems from `RCTWebSocket.xcodeproj` > `RCTSRWebSocket.m`. Has anyone experienced a similar issue after upgrading?

Development environment:

```
Environment:
  OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.6
  Node: 6.11.0
  Yarn: Not Found
  npm: 5.2.0
  Watchman: 4.9.0
  Xcode: Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
  Android Studio: 3.0 AI-171.4443003

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: ^16.3.0-alpha.2 => 16.3.0-alpha.2
  react-native: ^0.54.2 => 0.54.2
```

Source of error:

```
- (void)_failWithError:(NSError *)error;
{
  dispatch_async(_workQueue, ^{   <==== [Thread 14: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x30) ]
    if (self.readyState != RCTSR_CLOSED) {
      self->_failed = YES;
      [self _performDelegateBlock:^{
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(webSocket:didFailWithError:)]) {
          [self.delegate webSocket:self didFailWithError:error];
        }
      }];

      self.readyState = RCTSR_CLOSED;
      self->_selfRetain = nil;

      RCTSRLog(@"Failing with error %@", error.localizedDescription);

      [self _disconnect];
    }
  });
}
```

I read somewhere that this crash will not occur in a production application but I do not want to try and find out if that's true or not..

Answer (score 0):

I get an error related with WebSocket on compile time, to fix it check the "build phases" section of RCTWebSocket.xcodeproj and look inside the tab "Link binary with libraries", you should have libfishhook.a there, delete it and add it again